# Get object of specific integer element

Tags: php, arrays, object

```
$ActionData = '{"1":"muk",
                    "2":"goy",
                    "3":"sag",
                    "formname":"leadform1",
                    "skip":"true"
                  }';
    $form_field = json_decode($ActionData);
    print_r($form_field);
    echo $form_field->1;
```

I have an error on `echo $form_field->1;`
what am i making mistake there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add true in your code like

```
$form_field = json_decode($ActionData, true);
```

it works for me

Answer (score 4):

Use curly braces.

```
echo $form_field->{1};
```

**Total Program:**

```
<?php
$ActionData = '{"1":"muk",
                    "2":"goy",
                    "3":"sag",
                    "formname":"leadform1",
                    "skip":"true"
                  }';
$form_field = json_decode($ActionData);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($form_field);
echo '</pre>';

echo '<pre>';
echo $form_field->{1};
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

**Output:**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [1] => muk
    [2] => goy
    [3] => sag
    [formname] => leadform1
    [skip] => true
)

muk
```

Answer (score 2):

use `json_deocde` with true as second parameter and access the associative array.

```
$ActionData = '{"1":"muk",
                    "2":"goy",
                    "3":"sag",
                    "formname":"leadform1",
                    "skip":"true"
                  }';
    $form_field = json_decode($ActionData, true);
    echo $form_field[1]; //muk
```

> Also you can do it using the curly braces as Pupil suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Access the element as below.

```
echo $form_field['1'];
```